# Animation when clicking an edittext

Tags: android, animation

I have a simple animation. Only disappear edittext when clicked and then, open an activity.
But by clicking the edittext it is not disappearing. The animation is happening when I go back to activity where edittext is.
Where is my mistake?

Anim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"/>

</set>
```

Activity code:

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_1);
        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation animationSet = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slideoutedittext);
                editText1.setAnimation(animationSet);
                animationSet.setDuration(500);
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
            }

        });
```

Comment: what do you need? hide your edittext?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide my edittext. What is missing is to put View.Gone in edittext?

Comment: did you try using View.GONE  ?

Comment: I do not want edittext to simply hide. I want you to hide with this animation. But by putting Gone, it worked.

Comment: so , is it working now ?

Comment: Yes, when I put edittext.setVisibilty (View.Gone), it worked

Comment: ok, so I put the answer below, could you mark as solved and vote up? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `View.GONE` after you set the animation :

```
editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_1);
        editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation animationSet = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slideoutedittext);
                editText1.setAnimation(animationSet);
                animationSet.setDuration(500);
                 editText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_1);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
            }

        });
```